# Novo perfil no SOEN, para quando no SOpt?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, perfil

Acabei de receber a notificação sobre as novas funcionalidades no SOEN onde temos um "ponto-de-situação" bastante interessante e com uma análise mais chamativa sobre a nossa evolução no site.

Exemplo do URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/352449/zuul

Que deverão alterar para:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/idDoUtilizadorAqui/nickAqui
```

## Pergunta

Para quando no SOpt ?

Comment: Eu estava a fazer a mesma pergunta, mas já que você já fez +1. Porém apenar de ter novas funcionalidades, eu achei a aba perfil um pouco bagunçada, ou melhor dizendo poluída. Várias tarefas em um local espalhadas em um local não me parece a melhor maneira de obter produtividade, mas talvez seja falta de costume... :)

Comment: [Em 6 a 8 semanas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: @bfavaretto Brutal! :D

Comment: Quando o SUpt for lançado. Oh, wait...

Comment: Deve existir também algum critério para esse período, certo? Vejo que no [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) já foi atualizado.

Comment: @Gabe? ... alguma indicação?